# how to derive a conditional covariance matrix (symbolically)

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics

I have searched the database of the questions asked in this forum but to my surprise I could not find any satisfactory answer to my relatively simple question.

Given a vector of random variables `(X1,X2,X3,X4)` all having a normal distribution with mean `(m1,m2,m3,m4)` and variance `(v1,v2,v3,v4)`. Each random variable is respectively conditioned to signals `(s1,s2,s3,s4)`. I can compute manually covariance, say, between `X1` and `X2` as:

> Cov(X1,X2|s1,s2)=E{(X1-m1s1)(X2-m2s2)|s1,s2}
>
> where conditional mean of `X1` given `s1` is denoted by
>
> `m1s1` = E[X1|s1] and similarly,
>   `m2s2` = E[X2|s2] and 
>   E[X1X2|s1,s2] = `Integrate[X1X2, p(X1X2|s1,s2), {X1, -inf, inf},{X2, -inf, inf}]`

I can of course go ahead and derive all the elements of `conditional covariance matrix`. I thought that `Mathematica` can derive this conditional covariance matrix.

My ultimate objective is to calculate with a given set data the following ratio:

> Det[Covariance matrix for X]/Det[Conditional covariance matrix X|S]

Any idea about how to achieve this?

Comment: What does "conditioned to signals" mean?

Comment: @JimB: consider `X1` as an unknown true parameter and there is a signal about `X1`, i.e., `S1=X1+e1` all is normally distributed. Other RVs are also in the same form like `S2=X2+e2` where `e1 and e2` are noises about the respective RVs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I wonder if this post is helpful:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161352/conceptual-proof-that-conditional-of-a-multivariate-gaussian-is-multivariate-gau.

Comment: @JimB: I will take a look at the site you sent. I hope it is sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: @JimB: In fact, the very last part of the explanation given in the link you sent me (about conditional mean and conditional covariance) is what I am after. However, my problem is to derive it using `Mathematica`. In a simple case (say, X1 and s1), few days ago you have given me the answer in the context of mutual information. Now with current question, I want to move on to the multivariate case of mutual information, which requires the calculation of unconditional and conditional covariance matrices. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Sorry...one more question:  Are $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ mutually independent?

Comment: @JimB: `(X1, X2, X3, X4)` are not mutually independent, but are allowed to have zero covariance. In addition,  `X1 and e1`,  `X2  and e2` etc are independent and `e1`, `e2` are white noise.

Comment: @JimB: Following up my earlier comment on mutual independence, I like to know what kinds of complications arise in case of mutual dependence, and what kinds of simplicities imposed in case of mutual independence.

Comment: @JimB: Here is the final answer to your question. The random variables `X=(X1, X2, X3, X4)` are  independent and they are also conditionally independent given `S=(s1,s2,s3,s4)`. Finally, `(X,S)` has a multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85789/discussion-between-jimb-and-tugrul-temel).